# jquery find hidden fields only if they have associated checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, html

I have a series of checkboxes and hidden fields like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox">Option 1
<input type="hidden">uid of option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox">Option 2
<input type="hidden">uid of option 2
```

What is the specifier I need to use for jquery find in order to get the values(uids) of the hidden fields only if their associated checkbox has been selected?  I want to do $(specifier).serialize().

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('input[type="hidden"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).prev().is(':checkbox:checked')
})
```

If you want to serialize then make sure that you assign name attributes to the the hidden elements

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ph3Yv/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var hiddvalue=[];//make a array to store hidden value related to checked checkbox
$(":checkbox:checked").each(function(){
hiddvalue.push($(this).next(":hidden").val());//push value in array

});
alert(hiddvalue.join(","));//now value show with comma seprated
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs at http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

> Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked.

So if you use this format for your checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" value="uid of option 1">Option 1
<input type="checkbox" name="chkbox2" value="uid of option 2">Option 2
```

You should be able to then use:
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').serialize()